# Add program arguments in google dataflow program other than pipeline execution parameters

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I want to add runtime parameters to google dataflow code other than pipeline execution parameters while executing the maven command.

I am expecting to see it as "args[]" object in the main method.

How do i do it?

Comment: Can you use the same mechanism used by Dataflow and create custom options: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/specifying-exec-params#creating-custom-options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dataflow pipelines still have `main` methods that receive an array of string options. See the [WordCount example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/examples/WordCount.java#L192).

That said, extending pipeline options is also a good way of adding options that are automatically parsed. The WordCount example also [adds some parameters to PipelineOptions](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/examples/wordcount-example#using-parameterizable-pipelineoptions).